# dynamic_cast confusion

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I give up on this...

> $5.2.7/2- "If T is a pointer type, v
>   shall be an rvalue of a pointer to
>   complete class type, and the result is
>   an rvalue of type T. If T is a
>   reference type, v shall be an lvalue
>   of a complete class type, and the
>   result is an lvalue of the type
>   referred to by T."

In accordance with the above, the following code should be well-formed.

```
struct A{};
struct B : A{};

int main(){
   B b;
   A a, &ar1 = b;

   B& rb1 = dynamic_cast<B&>(ar1);  // Does not $5.2.7/2 apply here?
   B& rb2 = dynamic_cast<B&>(a);    // and also here?
}
```

But it is not. All compilers complain about the operand to dynamic_cast not being polymorphic in accordance with

> $5.2.7/6- Otherwise, v shall be a
>   pointer to or an lvalue of a
>   polymorphic type (10.3).

So my question is what does $5.2.7/2 mean? Why does $5.2.7/6 kick in here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Otherwise" in this case means, "unless the conditions in 5.2.7/5 apply".

You can tell this because /2 places a requirement on the program regarding the operand of the the `dynamic_cast` (note the "shall" language of "v shall be an lvalue" vs. the "is" language of "the result is an lvalue"). In common with other places in the standard, expressing a requirement doesn't necessarily mean that it's the *only* requirement. Other clauses can state extra requirements. In this case, /6 states an extra requirement that only applies in certain cases, depending on T and the static type of v.

/3, /4, /5 are telling you about the *value* of the result, and they're entirely consistent with the requirement in /2. None of them starts with "Otherwise". So to me it's fairly obvious that they do not form an "else if" chain starting at /2.

Some brackets or something might make this clearer (i.e. that the "otherwise" in /6 applies to the "if" in /5, and not to the "if" in /2, /3, or /4). But that's just not the house style.

Aside from anything else, the "otherwise" in /5 logically cannot meaningfully apply to the conditions in /2. /1 says that T must be "pointer or reference to complete class type, or *cv* `void*` ". /2 covers two cases - pointer types, and reference types. That's everything. There is no "otherwise" to /2 (unless it were to say "otherwise, a conforming compiler must issue a diagnostic", but that's implicit)

Comment: is there any other case where 'otherwise' in the Standard is used in a *potentially* unclear manner

Comment: what is the difference b/w 'shall' and 'will' as used in the Standard?

Comment: I don't promise that it's 100% consistent, but "shall" is used to emphasise that something is a restriction/requirement (either on the program or on the implementation, depending on context). "will" or "is" is used to state something that you can rely on being true, as opposed to something you actually do. Of course most of those "is" things also end up being requirements on the implementation somewhere down the line, so it's mostly a question of emphasis.

Comment: Here is another thought I had 'If T is a pointer type, v shall be an rvalue of a pointer to complete class type, and the result is an rvalue of type T.'. Since this talks of 'T = pointer, v = Rvalue', I thought that /6 talks of 'T = pointer, v = lvalue'. I see some merit in this thought

Comment: @Chubsdad: I see what you mean, but the text is "If T is a pointer type, *v shall be* an rvalue", not "If T is a pointer, *and v is* an rvalue". That leaves no room for v to be anything other than an rvalue pointer to a complete class type. The more you read the standard, the more you get used to dealing with its little subtleties... In this case there's another subtlety, though, which is that lvalues convert to rvalues. So in fact v *can* be an expression that *could* be treated as an lvalue, but /2 is saying that it will be treated as an rvalue. The restriction is the type.

Comment: @Chubsdad: found another ambiguous "otherwise". 4.7/3: "If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined." Reading that in isolation, you wouldn't know whether the "otherwise" applies to "if it can be represented", or "if the destination type is signed". It's the former, of course, since the previous para says what happens if the the destination type is unsigned.

Answer (score 9):

Well, all requirements in 5.2.7 should be observed *together*. You can't just stop after 5.2.7/2 and start writing code that supposedly satisfies everything "up to 5.2.7/2". The entire 5.2.7 defines the specification of `dynamic_cast`.

The polymorphic requirement is singled out because it is *conditional*. When you use `dynamic_cast` for upcasts, the polymorphic requirement does not apply (in fact, `dynamic_cast` is equivalent to `static_cast` in upcasts). The polymorphic requirement only applies when you use `dynamic_cast` for downcasts or crosscasts.

The specification of `dynamic_cast` is organized sequentially, meaning that it takes care of simpler cases first, and then proceeds to more complicated applications. You are supposed to read it step by step, until it covers your specific situation. Everything you read along that path applies cumulatively, And "otherwise" means: "if we haven't covered your case yet, then continue reading".

Comment: Mmmm. Okay. But what does "otherwise" mean?

Comment: exactly my question. The user of 'otherwise' in many other parts of the Standard gives kind of 'step wise' algorithmic proceed.

Comment: Thanks AndreyT. I think Steve put it in a manner which was convincing. The 'otherwise' applies to 5.2.7/5 instead of to all of the previous clauses. I hope such confusions have a way of reaching the Standard committe for potential addressal.

Comment: it means there is no way of proper up-casting without object slicing, then dynamic_cast is of no use to upcast.

Answer (score 4):

In order to do a **downcast** as in your example, Struct A needs to be polymorphic, and have RTTI.  Here's an adjusted version that works, to a point:

```
struct A{virtual void f(){}};
struct B : A{};

int main(){
   B b;
   A a, &ar1 = b;

   B& rb1 = dynamic_cast<B&>(ar1);  // Does not $5.2.7/2 apply here?
   //B& rb2 = dynamic_cast<B&>(a);    // and also here?
}
```

By adding a virtual making it polymorphic, RTTI is enabled for the class, allowing downcasts.

Note that your second example cannot work - since you are casting a pod (`a`) to a reference to a pod - which is not allowed.

---

Update:

Your code is not allowed under 5.2.7.5 and is neither allowed under 5.2.7.6.  My adjustment makes it work under 5.2.7.6

Comment: Thanks Alex. However that's not my question.